# what's the difference between { } and [ ] in javascript

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Im coding a BackboneJS example app with the following syntax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var object = [];

    _.extend(object, Backbone.Events);
     object.on("alert", function(msg)
    {
       console.log("Your name is: "+msg);
     });

    object.trigger("alert","Sarah");
</script>
```

I noticed that the app works if the variable is defined like this

```
var object = {}
```

is there any difference between the two?

oh I found this example 
http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html

{} is used to pass JSON like this

```
var cat = {colour: "grey", name: "Spot", size: 46};
```

[] is just an array

```
var cat = ["color one", "color two", "color three"];
```

thanks

Comment: Well {} isn't strictly used for JSON. It's used to instantiate javascript objects in general but I understand the confusion.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Not exactly everything. Both are objects (though one is a special `Array` object).

Comment: so what exactly would be the difference between var object = {} and var object = null 

aren't they both empty variables? since a variable is an object too, im confused =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `[]` is an [array literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Array_literals):

> An array literal is a list of zero or more expressions, each of which
>   represents an array element, enclosed in square brackets ([]).

- `{}` is an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals):

> An object literal is a list of zero or more pairs of property names
>   and associated values of an object, enclosed in curly braces ({}).

Comment: all answers were good, but this one is the best

Answer (score 3):

In short: [] is an array and {} is an object.

```
[] is shorthand for new Array()
{} is shorthand for new Object()
```

Basically, an Array is also an Object, but with added functionality. It is however, discouraged to use the Array as a hashmap (so, using strings as accessors).

Also, in your code the Array seems to be extended to have some sort of event mechanism. Personally I would use an object rather than an array but I guess there are reasons for this?

```
var object = [];
_.extend(object, Backbone.Events);
 object.on("alert", function(msg)
{
   console.log("Your name is: "+msg);
 });

object.trigger("alert","Sarah");
```

Comment: thanks, there is actually no reason for this, the original code is coded with "{}" too